# Object can be null. TS

Tags: angular, typescript, object, null

(ingredients | async).***ingredients*** -> Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531)

Where do i use any methods to pass this error?

```
<a class="list-group-item" style="cursor: pointer;"
*ngFor="let ingredient of (ingredients | async).ingredients; let i = index" (click)="onEditItem(i)"> {{ ingredient.name}} ({{ ingredient.amount}}) </a>
```

```
export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ingredients: Observable<{ ingredients: Ingredient[] }>;
  private inChnageSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private slService: ShoppingListService,
    private loggingService: LoggingService,
    private store: Store<{ shoppingList: { ingredients: Ingredient[] } }>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.ingredients = this.store.select('shoppingList');
  }
```

Comment: (ingredients | async)?.ingredients should fix it

Comment: Which version of Angular did you get this issue?